# Stability and @Stable annotation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

#### Stability and Skippability

In jetpack Compose stability, not triggering recomposition when inputs of a function hasn't changed, is achieved by using immutable variables or/and using @Immutable or @Stable annotation to make functions skippable as can be seen in detail in articles below.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8
https://chrisbanes.me/posts/composable-metrics/

> Skippable — when called during recomposition, compose is able to skip
> the function if all of the parameters are equal with their previous
> values.

And types can be

> Types could be immutable or stable:
>
> Immutable — Indicates a type where the value of any properties will
> never change after the object is constructed, and all methods are
> referentially transparent. All primitive types (String, Int, Float,
> etc) are considered immutable.
>
> Stable — Indicates a type that is mutable, but the Compose runtime
> will be notified if and when any public properties or method behavior
> would yield different results from a previous invocation.

`@Immutable` is pretty straightforward and not part of this question.

#### @Stable Annotation and Questions

> Stable is used to communicate some guarantees to the compose compiler
> about how a certain type or function will behave. When applied to a
> class or an interface, Stable indicates that the following must be
> true:
>
> 1. The result of equals will always return the same result for the same
>    two instances.
> 2. When a public property of the type changes, composition will be
>    notified.
> 3. All public property types are stable.
>
> When applied to a function or a property, the Stable annotation
> indicates that the function will return the same result if the same
> parameters are passed in. This is only meaningful if the parameters
> and results are themselves Stable, Immutable, or primitive.

In first article by Ben Trengrove it's shown as

```
@Stable
class MyStateHolder {
  var isLoading by mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

However, a class that only holds stable `MutableState` is already **stable**, what's the point of using `@Stable` annotation here?

A class i created

```
class MyUiState {
    var counter by mutableStateOf(0)
    var text by mutableStateOf("")
    var items by mutableStateOf(listOf(1, 2, 3))
}
```

logs

```
stable class MyUiState {
  stable var counter$delegate: MutableState<Int>
  stable var text$delegate: MutableState<String>
  stable var items$delegate: MutableState<List<Int>>
  <runtime stability> = Stable
}
```

When i add a public or private unstable param, a List, it becomes unstable

```
class MyUiState(
    var list: List<Int> = listOf()
) {
    var counter by mutableStateOf(0)
    var text by mutableStateOf("")
    var items by mutableStateOf(listOf(1, 2, 3))
}
```

logs

```
unstable class MyUiState {
  unstable var list: List<Int>
  stable var counter$delegate: MutableState<Int>
  stable var text$delegate: MutableState<String>
  stable var items$delegate: MutableState<List<Int>>
  <runtime stability> = Unstable
}
```

When i add `@Stable` annotation it becomes stable but

Doesn't adding an **unstable** public param already violate item number 3, and the contract? As i checked it doesn't recompose without changing param but definition says it should not be, right?

> 3. All public property types are stable.
>
> When applied to a function or a property, the Stable annotation
> indicates that the function will return the same result if the same
> parameters are passed in. This is only meaningful if the parameters
> and results are themselves Stable, Immutable, or primitive.

Also in first article mentions

> You should be very careful about the usage of these annotations as
> overriding the compiler behavior could lead you to unforeseen bugs
> should you get it wrong. If it is possible to make your class stable
> without an annotation, you should strive to achieve stability that
> way.

Is there any example that `@Stable` annotation is used incorrectly and could lead potential bugs? If possible an example with `@Immutable` would be nice to see how wrong usage breaks recomposition.

Comment: Also, why Color class is annotated as `@Stable` instead of `@Immutable` since it doesn't have immutable params?

Comment: Hey @Thracian sir may I get a little bit help of you here on my new question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344040/how-to-avoid-recomposition-in-lazycolumn-lazyrow thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an unstable public property to a @Stable class, it does indeed violate item number 3 of the @Stable contract, which states that "All public property types are stable." However, the @Stable annotation is not intended to enforce immutability or stability on properties; rather, it serves as an indication to Compose about the stability of the class as a whole.

While the addition of an unstable property might violate the contract, Compose still allows you to mark the class as @Stable. This means that Compose will assume the class is stable and may optimize based on that assumption. However, if the unstable property changes, Compose might not be notified, potentially leading to incorrect behavior or UI glitches.

Also, the decision to use @Stable for the Color class is a design choice to leverage Compose's recomposition optimizations effectively while acknowledging that UI elements using colors may have mutable states and behavior. It allows Compose to optimize based on the stability of the UI elements while still accommodating the potential for changes in color values based on the state.