# How to replace multiple lambda () -> Unit in a composable in Jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to replace multiple  lambda () -> Unit in a composable  in Jetpack compose android

```
 @Composable fun ChatMessageDisplay (
    authorName: String,
    author ImageUrl: String,
    dateSent: String,
    messages: List<Content>,
    likeCounts: List<Int>,
    onLikeClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    onMessageClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    onMessageLongClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    onUserPhotoClick: () -> Unit,
    onVisibleOnScreen: (Int) -> Unit,
    onShareClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    onEditClick: (Int) -> Unit,
    )
```

I have above composable Which requires   multiple  lambda () -> Unit

how can we replace them with a single lambda () -> Unit or any simple method to reduce multiple lambda () -> Units

Comment: Good ol' interface

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single lambda that takes a sealed class or an enum as its parameter

Here

```
sealed class ChatMessageEvent {
   data class LikeClick(val messageId: Int) : ChatMessageEvent()
   data class MessageClick(val messageId: Int) : ChatMessageEvent()
   data class MessageLongClick(val messageId: Int) : ChatMessageEvent()
   object UserPhotoClick : ChatMessageEvent()
   data class VisibleOnScreen(val messageId: Int) : ChatMessageEvent()
   data class ShareClick(val messageId: Int) : ChatMessageEvent()
   data class EditClick(val messageId: Int) : ChatMessageEvent()
```

}

Then modify *ChatMessageDisplay* composable to take a single lambda parameter that accepts a *ChatMessageEvent*

```
@Composable
fun ChatMessageDisplay(
   authorName: String,
   authorImageUrl: String,
   dateSent: String,
   messages: List<Content>,
   likeCounts: List<Int>,
   onEvent: (ChatMessageEvent) -> Unit
) {
  // Implementation where you call onEvent with the appropriate event
   // For example, for a like click:
   // IconButton(onClick = { onEvent(ChatMessageEvent.LikeClick(messageId)) })
}
```

Then you can handle the event in the caller

```
  ChatMessageDisplay(
    authorName = "ME",
    authorImageUrl = "url_to_image",
    dateSent = "2024-02-26",
    messages = listOf(),
    likeCounts = listOf(),
    onEvent = { event ->
    when (event) {
        is ChatMessageEvent.LikeClick -> {
            // Handle like click
        }
        is ChatMessageEvent.MessageClick -> {
            // Handle message click
        }
        is ChatMessageEvent.MessageLongClick -> {
            // Handle message long click
        }
        ChatMessageEvent.UserPhotoClick -> {
            // Handle user photo click
        }
        is ChatMessageEvent.VisibleOnScreen -> {
            // Handle visible on screen
        }
        is ChatMessageEvent.ShareClick -> {
            // Handle share click
        }
        is ChatMessageEvent.EditClick -> {
            // Handle edit click
        }
      }
    }
   )
```

Comment: @Muranio Does interface will not work instead of sealed class? Another question is  for stability issue for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76668544). Is sealed class is also unstable?

Comment: I don't think interface is a good approach for this question. using it will move the logic to another implementation class. but you can paste your approach to review.

in this case, I could only think of enum or sealed class

Comment: I have same problem of using so many lambda function in single composables.

Comment: Is sealed class is stable?

Comment: If I try to understand  what you meant by stability, you meant recomposition?

Sealed class is stable and in this case that you handle an event or data, you want your class to be recompose.

it might not be a good approach in some situation but I think it is good and flexible approach for this

Comment: Yes stability for recomposition. If you want take a look of [Stability in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability). I was taking about this...

Comment: in this case, we are dealing with event and data so you want your data to recompose

Also, you can also update your approach if you want it to be immutable

Comment: In newer Kotin versions you should use data objects: Use `data object UserPhotoClick : ChatMessageEvent()` instead of `object UserPhotoClick : ChatMessageEvent()` as described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#data-objects

Answer (score 0):

You may use viewModel and event To manage the events that is happening in a particular screen. I had learned about this process in recent times only by seeing the video of [this person on Youtube](https://youtu.be/bOd3wO0uFr8?si=WFaesHXm7b5gyNC0). He had made a different app but used the same approach. You may also take reference from him for better understanding.

My approach is like this ->

1. ChatMessageState.kt -

   ```
    data class ChatMessageState(
    val authorName: String = "",
    val authorImageUrl:String = "",
    val dataSent:String = "",
    val messages : List<String> = listOf("something"),
    val likeCounts: List<Int> = listOf(1,3)
     )
   ```
2. ChatMessageEvent.kt->

   ```
    sealed interface ChatMessageEvent {

    data class SetAuthorName(val authorName: String): ChatMessageEvent
    data class SetAuthorImageUrl(val authorImageUrl:String): ChatMessageEvent
    data class SetDataSent(val dataSent: String): ChatMessageEvent
    data class AllMessages(val messages: List<String>) : ChatMessageEvent
    data class SetLikeCounts(val likeCounts: List<Int>) : ChatMessageEvent
    object onLikeClick: ChatMessageEvent
    object onMessageClick: ChatMessageEvent
    object onMessageLongClick: ChatMessageEvent
    //Include more events that may occur in this screen


     }
   ```
3. ChatMessageViewModel.kt->

   ```
    class ChatMessageViewModel(
    // Use if any constructor is required
    ): ViewModel() {

    fun onEventTriggers(event: ChatMessageEvent){
        when(event){
            is ChatMessageEvent.SetAuthorName -> {
                // Write logic what you want to do in setting author name
            }
            ChatMessageEvent.onMessageClick -> {
                //Write logic what you want to do on Message clicked
            }

            //Add all events you had saved as events in ChatMessageEvent .

            else -> {}
        }
    }

    }
   ```
4. ChatMessageScreen.kt->

   ```
    @Composable fun ChatMessageScreen(
    state: ChatMessageState,
    viewModel: ChatMessageViewModel
    ){
    //Now use the onEvent function of viewModel to manage state 
     and other UI //things .
      }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I see you drew inspiration from [Thinking in Compose](https://youtu.be/SMOhl9RK0BA?si=zpVfVD8T7IKMBVJV&t=616)

I believe the Event Sinker described by @Muraino is the proper way to handle events; You have an Event Sinker (the `onEvent` lambda) that
that could even be passed along multiple Compose layers. You could also annotated with `@Immutable` your Events, if they are
data classes and contain only `val`s.
The EventSinker is an approach also used by [Circuit](https://slackhq.github.io/circuit/), an MVP library used for navigation, created by Slack.

Now, if you want to get rid of even **more** parameters, I suggest moving them to an `UiModel`.
I can't say for sure, but I believe you want to show a list of messages from an User. In this case, you could bundle all the data in a `UiModel`, like so:

```kotlin
@Immutable
data class MessagesUiModel(
    val authorName: String,
    val authorImageUrl: String,
    val likesCount: List<Int>,
    val messages: List<Content>,
    val dateSent: String,
)
```

You'll end up with something like:

```kotlin
@Composable fun ChatMessageDisplay (
    val messagesUiModel: MessagesUiModel,
    val eventSinker: (ChatEvent) -> Unit,
)
```

Of course, how you model your UiModel depends on the data you need. You could split your UiModel in smaller UiModels should you need it,
but overall, using an EventSinker together with one (or more) UiModels will reduce the number of paramters in your Composables.