# How to avoid recomposition in LazyColumn/LazyRow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a `@Composable` that is cross over features on my app, the thing is now I'm starting to integrate with them and when I'm adding my `@Composable` as an `item {}` what I'm seeing is that the `viewModel` is called many times (when the item is not visible and returns visible).

Is there I can avoid this?

Example of code :

My `@Composable`

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val component = rememberComposableDaggerComponent()

    val viewModel = remember { component.viewModel }
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
```

This is because my `@Composable` does a request when initialised it means that on my `ViewModel` in the `init{}` I have a request where I update the state of the UI.

### First problem

The first load, the item is not visible because the first state I send is `Empty` and then once the request is done I change the state to `Data`, this change I was expecting to update the list as soon as the state changes but I need to interact with the `LazyColumn` to print my `@Composable`.

How I'm updating the state?

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<MyObject>(MyObjectState.Empty)
override val uiState: StateFlow<MyObject>
    get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

Here the first load is an `Empty` state that means that the `@Composable` is not even shown because I do not have any loader on it if the request is done correctly I want to show the `@Composable` otherwise doesn't even show the `@Composable`.

```
private fun getFoo() {
        scope.launch {
            myUseCase().fold(
                onSuccess = { myData ->
                    if (myData.isEmpty()) {
                        _uiState.emit(MyObjectState.Error)
                    } else {
                        _uiState.emit(MyObjectState.Data(myData)
                    }
                },
                onFailure = _uiState.emit(MyObjectState.Error),
            )
        }
    }
```

So on my `@Composable` I do have this :

```
when (uiState) {
 is MyObjectState.Data -> //Surface etc to show the composable
 is MyObjectState.Error, MyObjectState.Empty -> {} // <-- So I don't show the Composable
```

What should I do to avoid calling the `viewModel.init` everytime the `@Composable` is not visible on the list and when is going to get visible again re-create the `ViewModel`?

I've been reading about `rememberSaveable` but it doesn't work with the entire `ViewModel`.

What I'd like to get with this question is to have a `@Composable` that calls its API call just once, if the API request return any error doesn't show the `@Composable` and don't even try to request again, if it returns OK then show the `@Composable` and remain it until the user leaves the screen of the list.

Is this going to happen even if I use a `Column` instead? I do not want to change the behavior of the other features just to integrate mine.

Comment: Did you consider providing the view model to your root composable as the function's parameter?

Comment: I cannot, because there are different features, I just provide a composable that inside of it is doing its business logic...

Comment: It is not clear what type of composable hierarchy you use. Can you provide some kind of schema  in your question?

Comment: I have a LazyColumn where for instance inside of this there are composable items of Cats, now I want to add my Discount composable at the top of the list

Comment: You might have to move the item out of the LazyColumn. And just have it above it but it would look like it was at the top of the list. To keep LazyColumn from recomposing you'd  need to move it out or maybe try a LaunchedEffect?